# Lua: Calling c method that returns userdata to Lua

Tags: objective-c, lua

Im using LuaObjcBridge and I'm calling a method from Lua like this:

```
local position = owner:position()
```

In objective-c this returns a CGPoint struct with X and Y which the bridge converts into Userdata. So CGPoint struct -> Lua userdata. In Lua how would I access the X and Y values from the Userdata?

Comment: I have not used LuaObjcBridge but I have a fair amount of experience with Lua and a custom bridge. I looked at the code and I do not see any support in the metatable to allow access to struct members. It appears that the metatable only tries to bridge objective C methods for full objects.You could try position.x or position.y but it does not look like those would work. In this case you could write your own bridged C functions that would extract the values from the userdata.

Comment: I wrote a lengthy answer for doing this in c++ by hand.  I know its not exactly what you are asking for but it may help.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481856/sending-variable-pointers-back-and-forth-between-c-and-lua/3506654#3506654  The only difference would be the way that classes are composed is c++ vs. obj-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to:

- define metatable, that contains methods that operate on userdata
- set metatable on userdata
- set the same metatable as __index field on userdata

or:

- set some methods that operate on userdata
- expose them to Lua

look at http://www.lua.org/pil/28.1.html

userdata can't do anything by itself, you need to add methods that do something with it.