# Using C++ objects in Lua scripts

Tags: c++, object, lua, lua-api, lua-userdata

How I can use C++ objects in lua script?

example class:

```
class cMyClass
{
 int a;
 void myTest(int b){};
}

cMyClass MyObject;
```

example using in lua(is what i need):

```
MyObjectLuaName.myTest(7);
MyObjectLuaName.a=12;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22515908/using-straight-lua-how-do-i-expose-an-existing-c-class-objec-for-use-in-a-lua/22558439#22558439) will help

Comment: much easier: [luabridge](http://vinniefalco.com/LuaBridge/Manual.html) (no boost), [luabind](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind.html) using boost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Use C++ Objects in Lua" -  for me that shouts for an "userdata" object!

http://loadcode.blogspot.de/2007/02/wrapping-c-classes-in-lua.html (this one is nice)
http://rubenlaguna.com/wp/2012/12/09/accessing-cpp-objects-from-lua/

That does exactly what you need.